# Why the line is not copied in the address space of child process?

Tags: ipc

```
   #include<stdio.h>---->(1)
    int main()
    {
        int i;
        int j,K;
        j = 200;
        K = 300;
        printf("Before forking: j = %d, K = %d\n ", j, K);---->(2)
        i = fork();---->(3) /* Calling fork() */
       if (i > 0) { /* Parent Process */ ----->(4)    
         sleep(10);/* Delay the parent */
         printf("After forking, parent: j = %d, K = %d\n", j, K);
       } ----->(5)

      else {----->(6)  /* Child process */
        j++;
        K++;
        printf("After forking, child: j = %d, K = %d\n", j, K);
      }---->(7)

   o/p of the above pgm is 
   Before forking: j = 200, K = 300
   After forking, child: j = 201, K = 301
   After forking, parent: j = 200, K = 300.
```

Since i am a beginner in IPC before going to the question first i want to make  sure  that my understanding is right.line# (1 )to line (2) & line (4) to line 5 constitute the parent process & line (6) to line (7) constitute the child process and anything above fork(),ie from line(1) to line (2)   is  anyways copied to the address space of child.Am i right about the above point?  Then  why is line# (2)  not printing twice,one in the child process and the other in the parent process.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the parent and the child continue from just after the call to `fork()`.  The child doesn't start again at the top of `main()`.

(You should use `fork()` followed immediately by `exec()` in the child if you want the child process to start from the beginning.)

Comment: >Then what does it meant by saying child gets a copy of its parent's address space.line no 2 is in the parents address space right?

Comment: @SubiPuthalath: Yes, but that line has already been executed.  The child continues *after* the `fork()`.

Comment: >Ok that i got.So you meant to say that only values of the variables(can be  in the heap or in the stack) only gets copied to childs address space.

Comment: *Everything* gets copied, including the values of variables, the code, and the point in the code that execution has reached.  The only difference as far as your code is concerned is the return value of `fork()`.  The presence of the code at (2) in the child doesn't mean that that code gets executed in the child - the point of execution is already beyond it.

Answer (score 0):

Child process inherit context of parent and continue to execute after fork(). Usually, exec() is called after folk() in child, exec() overwrite parent's context, and let child to run brand new.

Comment: >Thank you Eva for explanation